# Outlook 2013 rule with Run a Script to Update subject and forward mail

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-2013

I am trying to create a script that will add text to the subject of the email before it is forwarded. This is the first time I am writing one.

My criteria is set on the rule. The script will check the subject. Depending on the text in the subject it will add a certain text.

Example, the email I receive contains JobsDB in the subject then the text that should be added to the subject is Jobs DB. If the subject does not contains JobsDB then will go to next IF to check if it contains Indeed. If it does not it will go to another IF to check if it contains LinkedIn.

Current code:

```
Sub ForwardEmailIndeed(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

Set myForward = Item.Forward

If Item.Subject.Contains("Indeed") Then
    myForward.Subject = Item.Subject & ("Indeed")

If Item.Body.Contains("s1JOBS") Then
    myForward.Subject = Item.Subject & ("S1 Jobs")

If Item.Subject.Contains("JobsDB") Then
    myForward.Subject = Item.Subject & ("JobsDB")

If Item.Subject.Contains("TradeWindsJobs") Then
    myForward.Subject = Item.Subject & ("Tradewinds")

If Item.From.Contains("auto@oilandgasjobsearch.com") Or _
  Item.Body.Contains("oilandgasjobsearch.com") Then
    myForward.Subject = Item.Subject & ("Oil&Gas JobSearch")

If Item.From.Contains("LinkedIn") Or _
  Item.Body.Contains("LinkedIn") Then
    myForward.Subject = Item.Subject & ("Linkedin Advert")

End If

myForward.Recipients.Add "email@yahoo.com"

myForward.Send

End Sub
```

My rule works correctly but the script is not working.

This Code previously worked for me.

```
Sub ForwardEmail(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

    Set myForward = Item.Forward

    myForward.Subject = Item.Subject & (“Indeed”)
    myForward.Recipients.Add “email@yahoo.com”
    myForward.Send

End Sub
```

It does not work anymore. It does not forward anything.

Comment: So have you tried to step through your script to see what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for InStr not Contains.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264811%28v=office.15%29.aspx

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ForwardEmailIndeed_test()
' Open a mailitem first
Dim curritem As mailitem
Set curritem = ActiveInspector.currentItem
ForwardEmailIndeed curritem
End Sub


Sub ForwardEmailIndeed(Item As Outlook.mailitem)

Dim myForward As mailitem

Set myForward = Item.Forward

If InStr(Item.Subject, "Indeed") Then
    myForward.Subject = Item.Subject & ("Indeed")
End If

If InStr(Item.body, "s1JOBS") Then
    myForward.Subject = Item.Subject & ("S1 Jobs")
End If

If InStr(Item.Subject, "JobsDB") Then
    myForward.Subject = Item.Subject & ("JobsDB")
End If

If InStr(Item.Subject, "TradeWindsJobs") Then
    myForward.Subject = Item.Subject & ("Tradewinds")
End If

If InStr(Item.SenderEmailAddress, "auto@oilandgasjobsearch.com") Or _
  InStr(Item.body, "oilandgasjobsearch.com") Then
    myForward.Subject = Item.Subject & ("Oil&Gas JobSearch")
End If

If InStr(Item.SenderEmailAddress, "LinkedIn") Or _
  InStr(Item.body, "LinkedIn") Then
    myForward.Subject = Item.Subject & ("Linkedin Advert")
End If

myForward.Recipients.Add ("email@yahoo.com")

myForward.Send

End Sub


Private Sub ForwardEmail_test()
' Open a mailitem first
Dim curritem As mailitem
Set curritem = ActiveInspector.currentItem
ForwardEmailIndeed curritem
End Sub

Sub ForwardEmail(Item As Outlook.mailitem)

Dim myForward As mailitem
Set myForward = Item.Forward

myForward.Subject = Item.Subject & ("Indeed")
myForward.Recipients.Add ("email@yahoo.com")

myForward.Send

End Sub
```